# Is there an alternate way of saying "on your hand(s)" or one of your hands or both of them?

Tags: grammar

If there's blood on one of your hands, the machine will detect it.

If there's blood on one of your hands or both of them, the machine will detect it.

So, is there a way to rewrite the last sentence into a much shorter one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, in conversation, the following:

> The machine will detect any blood on your hands.

would be understood to mean that if there's blood on either hand, or on both, the machine will detect it.

Natural language in conversation is not treated as a specification, not treated as an instruction to a robot that could be confused by the slightest ambiguity. Hearing those words only a tiny number of native speakers would wonder what would happen if there was blood only on one hand.